# Can BigQuery API Call use API Key of Service Account?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

In google cloud I have a service account with big query access.

I would like to use API Key within bigquery api Request. Can this be done?

Paul

Comment: read this topic on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment) In general, you can use service account to authenticate when using BigQuery. The actual way to do this depends on the client you're using.

Comment: I am looking to do it as a call from a server to get a token to use an in bigquery api call.

do you have an example?

Comment: curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/#ProjectID#?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"datasetReference":{"datasetId":"xyz"}}' \
  --compressed

This is the format that the web page example shows.
In the API Key as part of https call trying to use code from API & Services - Credentials.
I am actually looking to do this through ansible using uri module.
However I am looking to just get curl to work from server initially.